# Is there a way to stop the zooming when you tap on a editable text field in a browser?

Tags: lumia, keyboard

Quite often, whatever I need to type is dependent on reading the text surrounding the box I am typing in. It's very annoying having to zooming back out every time I tap to type, because the default Windows Phone behaviour (if it's changeable at all) is to zoom all the way in on the text field. I can see why this can be useful, but I have good eyes, so I don't need this feature.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is the default behaviour and cannot be changed.

This is also the default behaviour on iOS and Android.